# how to use scss in use svelte 3

Tags: sass, svelte-3

I'm trying to use scss in svelte 3, i've done the steps placed in this post:
[scss guide in svelte 3](https://daveceddia.com/svelte-with-sass-in-vscode/)

but i keep receiving a syntax error

"Colon is expectedsvelte(css-syntax-error)"

in code like this:

```
<style type="text/scss">
  #container {
   display: flex;

     /*error in the div below*/
     div {
     background: red;
    }
  }
```

i've prettier setup too, but i don't think it's related

Comment: did you install correctly all dependencies as mentioned in your article link?

Comment: yes. I've even download again the base project and it keeps giving me the same error

Comment: Note that `<style lang="scss">` worked better for me.

Answer (score 18):

Node-sass is now deprecated, so above still applies but can just be
`npm install svelte-preprocess sass --save-dev` instead :)

Answer (score 18):

When you are using [`svelte-kit`](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/tree/master/packages/create-svelte) to create your svelte application, you don't need to change the `svelte.config.js` because it is already set up and it looks as follows:

```js
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-auto';
import preprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';

/** @type {import('@sveltejs/kit').Config} */
const config = {
    // Consult https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess
    // for more information about preprocessors
    preprocess: preprocess(),

    kit: {
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

All you have to do is to install `sass` using your package manager as follows:

```bash
yarn add -D sass
# or using npm
npm i --save-dev sass
```

And boom!! you will be able to style your components using `sass` or `scss` by just changing the attribute value for `lang` to either `sass` or `scss`

1. using `scss`

```html
<div class="app">
    <div class="app__bin">
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </div>
</div>

<style lang="scss">
    .app {
        .app__bin {
            h1 {
                color: red;
            }
        }
    }
</style>
```

2. Using `sass`

```html
<style lang="sass">
    .app 
        .app__bin
            h1
                color: red
</style>
```

> **Happy hacking with svelte!!**

Answer (score 9):

To add support for scss, you'll need add a pre-processor like [svelte-preprocess](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte-preprocess)

```
npm install svelte-preprocess node-sass --save-dev
```

In rollup.config.js:

```
import sveltePreprocess from 'svelte-preprocess';
```

and then under

```
plugins: [
    svelte({
        ...,
        preprocess: sveltePreprocess()
    }),
```

and restart the server.

To enables scss support in vscode create a svelte.config.js file:

```
const sveltePreprocess = require('svelte-preprocess')

module.exports = {
  preprocess: sveltePreprocess(),
}
```

And restart vscode